# What algorithms for finding function's extremum besides GA and SA exist in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization

GA - genetic algorithm. SA - simulated annealing.
I wanna use function of integer variables.
GA can be applied for discrete variables, but I heard that it isn't as fast as SA.
But SA uses only continuous variables.
What another algorithms in Matlab can someone use for function of discrete variables?

Comment: What is GA, what is SA? Did you read the documentation of the Optimization Toolbox?

Comment: GA - genetic algorithm. SA - simulated annealing. I didn't find another Matlab algs for extremum search. P.S. Edited my first message.

Comment: Well, there are other algorithms for continuous parameters, like gradient descent, Nelder–Mead etc. Simplest to use is `fminsearch`. But it appears you are right, there seem to be no discrete optimization algorithms.